# PHP "Notice: Undefined index"

Tags: php

This is really starting to get annoying...

I'm trying to create a register page where it sends the username, password and security level.

#### HTML form

```
<div class="login">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" name="register_form">
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <input type="text" name="level" placeholder="LEVEL" value="1" disabled="true"/>
        <button type="submit" name="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my PHP code which is in the same file...

```
<?php
    require 'config/db_connect.php';

    if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {
        session_start();
        $username = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $level = $_POST['level'];
        //$seccode = $_POST['seccode'];

        $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO secure_login (email, password, lvl) VALUES('{$username}', '{$password}','{$level}')");
    }
?>
```

And I keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: level in C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\register.php on line 8

Comment: disabled `input` elements don't get posted

Comment: side note: you should definitely(!) sanitize your inputs before pushing them into your database. and/or use parameterized queries. that code right there is predestined for [sql-injections](http://php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: As already stated - disabled input-elements does not get posted, you could use a `readonly` attribute instead.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Notice: Undefined index: level in C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\register.php on line 8
```

> Happens when you try to access an array by a key that does not exist in the array.

**Hint**: to check the exist of the variable do `print_r($_POST);`

> Values for disabled form elements are not passed to the processor
>   method. The W3C calls this a successful element.(This works similar to
>   form check boxes that are not checked.)

Instead of disabling the input you rather should add some Javascript to make it unable to edit it like:

```
var defaultValue = "hello";
element.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    this.value = defaultValue ;
});
```

or just use: `readonly` instaed of `disabled` or use: `style="display: none"`

For e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="level" placeholder="LEVEL" value="1" style="display: none"/>
```

*(I use this for hidden file upload forms.)*

**Because I got my coffee already:**

Your database connection is (more or less) insecure.
Try this example for a safe connection:

```
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $query->execute(array($username, $password));
    $db = null;
```

Comment: I put what you said to do "readonly" still getting the error aswel, and when i put in "print_r($_POST); it only showing the username and password ?

Comment: Then you did not delete the disabled. Updated with an 100% working example.

Comment: Can you visit me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript ?

Comment: Sorry can't not enough rep. And yeah still happening even with your code

Comment: Do following: add <input type="text" name="test" value="Hello!"/> to the DOM form and give me the print_r result.

Comment: Array ( [user] => Ace [pass] => ace [level] => 1 [test] => Hello! [Register] => )  i can see now the level is showing up but the error is still there aswel it's not adding to the database

Comment: $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO secure_login (email, password, lvl) VALUES('$username', '$password','$level')");

Comment: Uhh, thankyou! That fixed it!

Comment: Check my answer again for a better database example.